# Is it possible to use complex logic in DRF ViewSet Permission Classes?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

In the app I'm working on, I'd like it so that to create a task for a committee, you must be a member of the committee, the head of the committee, or an admin user, but you must also be authenticated. I understand this can be done with a few OR operators, but in the case that I need something more complex, I was hoping I could use nested lists of permission classes as such:

```py
permission_classes = [
                         IsAuthenticated & 
                         [
                             IsCommitteeHead | 
                             IsCommitteeMember | 
                             IsAdminUser
                         ]
                     ]
```

Will this syntax work properly, or does rest_framework not understand this?

Comment: You can define a custom permission. [i.e.](https://testdriven.io/blog/custom-permission-classes-drf/)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71139982

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy):

```
class ExampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated|ReadOnly]
```

> Note: it supports & (and), | (or) and ~ (not).

So in your case:

```py
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated &(IsCommitteeHead|IsCommitteeMember|IsAdminUser)]
```

#### Edit:

If using this notation inside `get_permissions`, you need to return class instances instead of classes. Note that entire expression should be one instance:

```
def get_permissions(self):
    return (
        IsAuthenticated & (IsCommitteeHead|IsCommitteeMember|IsAdminUser)
    )()
```

Comment: I understand I can use logical operators, but can they be used in nested groups and still be parsed properly? Also, as far as I can tell from what I've tried these formats do not work when using ModelViewSets and get_permissions() as it requires instances.

Comment: It works but it's a bit counterintuitive. I've edited my answer