# How to use django groups and perms in django-rest-framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, permissions

How to handle complex required permissions in any API using django-rest-framework?

For example, you have three tier support operators who have access to APIs, but they should only have access to respective endpoint and as the last tier, superadmin should have everything in hands.

How to solve this simple problem by django group and permissions?

There are lots of answers being related to AND or OR the perms in permission_classes like

```
def get_permissions(self):
    return (
    IsAuthenticated & (IsCommitteeHead|IsCommitteeMember|IsAdminUser)
    )()
```

or

```
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated &(IsCommitteeHead|IsCommitteeMember|IsAdminUser)]
```

but I think hard coding always makes the code a complete mess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new permission model permission from django base model permission like this:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import DjangoModelPermissions


class FullDjangoModelPermissions(DjangoModelPermissions):
    perms_map = {
        'GET': ['%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s'],
        'OPTIONS': ['%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s'],
        'HEAD': ['%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s'],
        'POST': ['%(app_label)s.add_%(model_name)s'],
        'PUT': ['%(app_label)s.change_%(model_name)s'],
        'PATCH': ['%(app_label)s.change_%(model_name)s'],
        'DELETE': ['%(app_label)s.delete_%(model_name)s'],
    }
```

And in view class like this:

```
class SomeAwuful(GenericAPIView):
    ...
    permission_classes = [FullDjangoModelPermissions]
    ...
```

Then you can go in Django admin dashboard and set who has access to what, or creating group to access features, like this:

[image: django-admin-perms]